# CSS content in @page margin boxes not showing when printing pdf

Tags: html, css, pdf, printing

I'm trying to use HTML to generate an ebook, i want to add heading and footer to each page and theorically there's properties of `@page` that allow this but when printing the pdf (`cmd+p`) from any browser (i'm on macOS Catalina, tried with chrome, firefox and safari) the content is not shown, while `size` and `margin` properties work fine.

This is a barebone example that has the same problem for me... does the in-browser `print pdf` command not support this stuff?

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
    @page {
        size: A5;
        margin: 10%;

        @top-left{
            content: "Page X" 
        }
    }
</style>
</head>    
<body>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a pharetra nunc. Fusce sed lacus auctor, sagittis dolor non, pellentesque dui. Vivamus porttitor interdum metus, in maximus ligula pretium sit amet. Praesent eu diam tortor. Pellentesque nibh lectus, rutrum a mattis non, pharetra eu ante. Sed ut libero et est pellentesque pretium nec vel ante. Integer pulvinar laoreet efficitur.
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Margin notes "theorically" does not work. You could add text centred at the top or bottom of the page by any other style setting means. Here is a tutorial that covers [customisation as per their own pages](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/reusable-html-components-how-to-reuse-a-header-and-footer-on-a-website/)
[image]

From Chrome / Edge perspective its supposed to be a ["Print clutter free"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/print-in-microsoft-edge-38f38d80-d55c-01a6-528d-467cdd8ada2d) output or begrudgingly a fixed header/trailer per page or else add page numbering text in afterwards. It has been thrashed over many ways/years and latest I found this year is from https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/headless-dev/c/UTxlzQFYRvI "I developed patch to enhance -print-to-pdf to allow to customize header and footer but the patch is going nowhere." is a comment from a co-developer, frustrated that is only "fixed format" on or off. The best you can do universally is use positional html and in page scripting with zero margin plus headings and footers off.

Print or create a PDF of a web page in Safari on Mac

When printing or creating a PDF of a web page, you can include its background image and colour, and **show the web address and date in headers and footers.**

To add the header and footer text in my browsers, I need to switch them on in the page printer dialog. So I hit print>More OPTIONS>OPTIONS>Headers and Footers>then they will be applied. The settings and their methods will vary from browser to browser.

Likewise with headless printing the user can set them on or off whilst printing.

Of course you can add any additional text anywhere on the page between them e.g. at the top and bottom. Microsoft suggest keep the margins free by about 1/2" to add them manually.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/discussions/edit-your-existing-headers-and-footers-in-edge/m-p/2463956/highlight/true#M48251

[image]

In older windows IE browser it was/(is?) possible for user to set them exactly as the user requires them to be.

https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/change-or-remove-headers-and-footers-when-printing-in-internet-explorer/

[image]

Ebook editors for content editing should provide a Page number (possibly header/footer) function or use an online service like  https://www.sejda.com/header-footer-pdf or
**for a very easy cross platform command line tool to stamp the "Page #" @Top-Left** see
https://www.coherentpdf.com/cpdfmanual/cpdfmanualch8.html#x12-690008

Comment: If you try to print an html file with the snippet that i attached you will see that enabling header/footer in the print options does NOT print the content that is defined in the css `content: "Page X`